# Fix issue with npm peerDependencies for particular package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

My application uses a set of domain packages that have the core as a peer dependency. All domain packages looks like the following:

```
"name": "domain-a-pckg",
"peerDependencies":{ "core-pckg": "^4.1.0" }
```

```
"name": "domain-z-pckg",
"peerDependencies":{ "core-pckg": "^8.9.0" }
```

The main issue, that some domain packages work fine with `4.1.0` but not with `8.9.0` of core-pckg and the rest work fine with `8.9.0` but not with `4.1.0`.
Is there a way to somehow configure, or disable peer dependencies, or replace modules? Other words is there a way to somehow fix that issue during install, deploy, build, etc?
I could have been re-released the packages, however, that solution is unacceptable for some reasons.

A package json:

```
"dependencies": {
   "domain-a-pckg": "^1.1.1",
   "domain-z-pckg": "^2.1.1",
   "core-pckg": "^4.1.1"
}
```

Comment: Why is that a problem? You can have multiple versions installed of the same dependency? Assuming you can't run dedupe and point them towards the same dependency in the package-lock file - I'd just install `domain-a-pckg` and `domain-z-pckg` and let NPM deal with it?

(As a fun fact in NPM 7 peerDependencies are installed automatically)

Comment: Because only one version of the `core-pckg` is installed and it will be used by all domain packages. Some of them will work, and some of the will fail.

Comment: What version of NPM are you using? In NPM if you have multiple dependencies with the same dependency it will just install multiple versions of the nested dependency it's supposed to "just work".

Comment: 6.14. I see just one core-pckg in the node_modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `yarn`:

```
"resolutions": {
   "domain-z-pckg/core-pckg": "8.9.0"
}
```

Npm currently does not have such feature. `npx force-resolutions` will replace all nested dependencies.